# Visual studio freeze - debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging, freeze

I am using VS2015 community(also enterprise) and everything was OK, but today when I start debugging any project -VS freeze. It is possible build it and build is success... but when I start debugging it freeze. I tried reinstall VS, use another version, delete Registry, delete all files about VS, everything...

[image: Print Screen when it freeze]
I am using C++.

Comment: Do you have avast anti-virus?

Comment: aaaaaaaaa thanks! i disable it and it works ! thanks a lot