# MSVS 2013 all new projects hang before entry point

Tags: visual-studio

I'm having trouble with Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013. I created a simple console project (VC++), wrote the code, built it and when I hit Run, instead of a console appearing, MSVS hung. I had to kill it from taskmgr. I tried recreating the project, using a different configuration (Release instead of Debug), changing the `int main()` to `void main()` and putting a breakppoint on the firs line but it didn't fix the issue. I tried running it from cmd, but it hung too (I could close the windows with X, but I had to kill the project from taskmgr). Getting desperate, I tried rebuilding an old (console) project I knew to be correct and it worked just fine. Then I tried using a template I had created from this (working) project before (and used it successfully before) to create a new project and it also hung. Then I tried creating a C# project and I could get `Console.ReadLine()` to display the console window. I also tried making a new Win32Project but alas, no luck.

I now also tried disassembling the compiled result with IDA, but the while it seemed correct, IDA also hung when I tried to debug from it. OllyDbg also just hangs.

Comment: We've been having this question all week long, uninstall Avast.

Comment: Hmm... I couldn't find any such questions. But yes, Avast was the problem.

Comment: Now that I looked through the visual-studio tag I an see them, but I couldn't find anything with Google. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33762535/1648883